# How to turn on my accessibility service on Amazon fire tv

Tags: android, accessibility, amazon-fire-tv

I have an app for android with accessibility service. I tried to run it on Amazon tv but it didn't work. In [Amazon website](https://developer.amazon.com/zh/docs/fire-tv/implement-accessibility-fire-os.html) [Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/zh/docs/fire-tv/differences-from-android-tv-development.html) claims there is no difference between the OS exclude the google service.
But I can't get access to my accessibility service.
How can I turn it on?

Comment: Hey @Maor-Hadad, I can see you haven't accepted an answer on any of your questions since 2016. It would be great if you could do that for any of the questions where the answer helped you, if you've just forgotten about it

Comment: Hi, @NickCardoso I do response answer / comments but if the answer is not suit my question I'm not going to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The accessibility service is a protected component so it is not possible to turn it on programatically.**

On my Amazon Fire tablets I can access my service directly through <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Accessibility</kbd> → <kbd>Services</kbd>. However, many Android TV's do not support all components.

[This article](https://support.google.com/androidtv/answer/6123320?hl=en) mentions that for TV, accessibility is in the <kbd>preferences</kbd> menu under <kbd>Services</kbd> so you should start by looking there.

Remember if your app is only the service, the app must first meet the [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start) to run on a TV, before you will see the service listed.

> Amazon claims there is no difference between the OS exclude the google service

Unfortunately this turns out not to be true. [This page](https://developer.amazon.com/zh/docs/fire-tv/differences-from-android-tv-development.html) actually lists many differences, but more useful is [this page](https://developer.amazon.com/zh/docs/fire-tv/implement-accessibility-fire-os.html) on implementing accessibility for TV. Amazon uses a different setup (VoiceView).

If you still cannot see your service, start with the link above and also make sure you have met [these guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service)

Comment: I have a working app with accessibility service on Android, but when I install it on amazon tv, I can't see my service altho it answer the accessibility service guidelines.